# Determine the architecture of a Mac from the command line or script?

Tags: macos, command-line, shell-script, powerpc

I'm writing a shell script, and I need to know the architecture, i.e. PPC or Intel. Back in the day, there was a program `/bin/arch` that told you, but my Mac doesn't seem to have it.

Is there an easy way I can do this? `grep` for something in a log file? Call some other program that spits that out as a side effect?

It would be nice to know what OS version I'm running too, but that may not be necessary.

Comment: `machine` did the job to me; see also [What does i386 mean on macOS Mojave?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/518320/98982)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

There are many ways, but try `uname -a`.

Comment: `uname -p` gives just the processor architecture. `man uname` for other options.

Comment: @DougHarris I get x86_64 with `-a` but i386 with `-p`

Comment: @GP89 Have the same condition with you.

Comment: @GP89 `i386` is the machine processor architecture, while `x86_64` is current hardware platform - from the man page.

Answer (score 27):

`uname -m` seems to output the same information as `/bin/arch`.

Comment: Not with me. `arch` outputs `i368` and `uname -m` outputs `x84_86`. I run OSX on a 64bit machine.

Comment: @ErikAigner: Typo, perhaps? Shouldn't it be `x86_64`?

Comment: Of course `arch` should return `x86_64`, that's why it's so strange. But I don't know why.

Comment: Same here:
$ uname -m
x86_64
$ arch
i386

Answer (score 22):

`arch` is available in `/usr/bin/arch`

You can get OS version information with `sw_vers`

```
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.6.3
BuildVersion:   10D573
$ sw_vers -productVersion
10.6.3
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `sysctl` to get information about your CPU:

```
$ sysctl machdep.cpu.brand_string
machdep.cpu.brand_string: Apple M1 Pro
```

Now you can take this string and search in the internet to get details about this CPU brand.

If you want more information about the CPU you can use this command:

```
$ sysctl machdep.cpu
machdep.cpu.cores_per_package: 10
machdep.cpu.core_count: 10
machdep.cpu.logical_per_package: 10
machdep.cpu.thread_count: 10
machdep.cpu.brand_string: Apple M1 Pro
machdep.cpu.features: FPU VME DE PSE TSC MSR PAE MCE CX8 APIC SEP MTRR PGE MCA CMOV PAT PSE36 CLFSH DS ACPI MMX FXSR SSE SSE2 SS HTT TM PBE SSE3 PCLMULQDQ DTSE64 MON DSCPL VMX EST TM2 SSSE3 CX16 TPR PDCM SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AES SEGLIM64
machdep.cpu.feature_bits: 151121000215084031
machdep.cpu.family: 6
```

Comment: Running any kind of EDR which might run on the client under rosetta makes this the only valid answer since this checks the underlaying machine itself and not the current prompt which might be wrong due to rosetta.

Answer (score 5):

Another method nobody mentioned is:

```sh
$ machine
arm64e
```

```
MACHINE(1)                                                               General Commands Manual                                                               MACHINE(1)

NAME
     machine – print machine type

SYNOPSIS
     machine

DESCRIPTION
     The machine command displays the machine type.
```